# Could not build module UIKit --- Xcode 8.3.3

Tags: ios, xcode

Today when I Archive my project( including run in devices),It stops and show Build Failed.

When I run it with Simulators it works well.

this is the error

> Could not build module UIKit

and some of system files show error like this:

[Could not build module UIKit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J07vK.jpg)

[system file errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQZJa.jpg)

I tried a lot but can't solve it.

- Clean（Cmd + K)
- Clean Build Folder
- Delete DerivedData
- Remove and add UIKit.framework
- Set the "Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework modules" setting to YES
- delete and reinstall Xcode 8.3.3

but it doesn't work for me!

thank you very much for read my question and help me!

Comment: I think you've changed header file. Therefore you can't build UIKit module.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened with me. I modified a file in UIKit framework accidentally and after that so many try I didn't fixed that issue.

Even I've tried to replace UIKit with new one. (You can try it.)

What I did is...

Delete Xcode from Application folder and reinstall it at same place.

Please make sure your Xcode is in Application folder.

Comment: thank you for answer my question.

i have checked my Xcode, it is ok.

Now i have removed a third_lib, and then it runs well.

Answer (score 0):

If you add c file into you project, in the pch file, you should modify 
**#import SomeHeaderFile** to

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import  SomeHeaderFile
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

This error accrued for me after updating my iPhone to new iOS version. After that I had to complete restart everything, including iPhone device and Mac. Afterwards I could update to recommended settings for my pods and everything works again.